# Excel: What is the syntax for 'for loops' with a specific selection of cells?

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I have a little problem with an Excel project I have.

I will be selecting a group of cells and I want a macro that when runs has a for loop that checks all the containing cells to see if their style is 'good' and if it is, add one to the total box

[image: Excel Example]

In this example, when I select the cells in this table and press the button the cell below total should read 5 because 5 of the cells in the table have the 'good' theme.

(lets say, for example, the cell under the 'Total' cell is D5)

Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and what problems you have run in to.

Comment: I suppose that you are talking about VBA code, then do not tag your question with unrelated tags. VBA is a different languange than VB.NET

Comment: @Steve It is? I'm sorry, I'm new to a lot of this :L

Comment: @RonRosenfeld It's not so much that I have a problem with what I know, It's that I don't really know where to start

Comment: Probably you should post on SuperUser.  This group is primarily to help people with code; it is not a code writing service.  But you start by adding a button; and attaching code that cycles through the relevant cells, using either a For Each ... Next loop, or by using a counter

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I considered posting on SuperUser, but wasn't sure.
Ok, I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what 'good style' is, but you can try something like that:

```
Sub CheckStyle()

  Dim rng As Range
  Dim total As Integer

  If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
    For Each rng In Selection
      'enter any 'good' style defintion below
      If rng.Style = "Good" Then
        total = total + 1
      End If
    Next rng

    'change d5 to result cell address below
    ActiveSheet.Range("d5").Value = total

  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe `total = total - CInt(rng.Style = "Good")`

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what you mean about the 'Good' style?

Comment: @Jeeped What would you replace with that?

Comment: @Jeeped thanks, I have corrected some typos in my code, but I think it's easier to read it in my version.

Comment: @user3964075 I have updated the code, it should work now.

Comment: @user3075190 - The three lines under the *enter any 'good' style defintion [sic] below* comment. Btw, 'Good' style are your words , not user3964075's.

Comment: @user3964075 Thank you both very much, it works perfectly, I'll remember this for next time. :)

Comment: @Jeeped - I saw 'good' in the OP's question and didn't know it's actually a built-in style name (I'm using different language version, but still it's not a best excuse...)

Comment: @user3964075 You set total to an integer, but what variable type is the excel currency format?

Comment: @user3075190 as simple as Currency

Comment: @user3964075 Oh ok xD. I was guessing things like 'float' and 'long'.

One last thing: I've slightly changed what you said, what's wrong with this?
`total = total + ActiveSheet.Range(F, rng)`

Comment: @user3075190, I assume that you want to get F column value for each row in some column, so the code should be `total = total + ActiveSheet.Range("F" & rng.Row).Value`

Comment: @user3964075 Wow, Thanks! You've been a Godsend :)